# File format lost when I use mozilla browser to download files saved in database

Tags: php, codeigniter, mozilla

I am uploading files and save them in database but when I download them,with the header returned when I download ; the file format and fileName are lost in Mozilla while chrome is working correctly.  I want to know what wrong with my codes. I supplied a segment of code for uploading and another for downloading.

For Ms word document, the returned header says the document is  **Microsoft Excel Worksheet (47.4 KB).**
 Have a look at my codes.
                    //Getting details of file to be uploaded

```
       $fileName =$suffix.$_FILES['report']['name'];
       $tmpName  = $_FILES['report']['tmp_name'];
        $fileSize = $_FILES['report']['size'];
        $fileType = $_FILES['report']['type'];
        $fp = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
        $content = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
        fclose($fp);
        if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc())
        {
            $fileName = addslashes($fileName);
        };
         `  
             `  $documentData=array(
                //  'periodId' => $this->input->post('period',true),
                'reporter'   =>  $this->session->userdata("userId"),
                'documentName'   =>  $fileName,
                'documentType'   =>  $fileType,
                'documentSize'   =>  $fileSize,rtv## Heading ##
                'document'=> $content,
                'date'  => date("Y/m/d"));`

$this->document_model->save($documentData);
```

Then I try to download the file using the following segment of codes:

`   public function download(){

```
    $key=$this->uri->segment(3);

    $query = "SELECT documentName, documentType, documentSize, document " 
            "FROM report_documents WHERE documentId='$key'";  `

     ` $result = mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed');
    list($name, $type, $size, $content) =mysql_fetch_array($result);

    header("Content-type: $type");
    header("Content-length: $size");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$name");
    echo $content;
    exit;

}
```

`

Comment: "loose file format" really don't know what that means

Comment: You mean: 'tab, ident or spaces between words'?

Comment: I mean to return the correct header of the document. If it was MS word to return Ms word when downloading

Comment: For Ms word document, the returned header says the document is **  Microsoft Excel Worksheet (47.4 KB)**

Comment: whats an example filename, and type?

Comment: The file name is 1378533599_1_students attendance list.docx, the correct type you see it a word document but when I download it, the pop up message says it is **Microsoft Excel Worksheet (47.4 KB)**